# Call external web service from within Crm 2016

Tags: plugins, workflow, microsoft-dynamics

I have some functionality I need to implement in Dynamics Crm 2016. I need to scan all records for a custom entity and update any record where a certain condition is true. This is a bit too complex to do via a workflow (I can't change owner via a workflow step) so I'm thinking perhaps I could perform this logic in a custom plugin. I don't know if it makes sense to call this plugin from a workflow in crm though, as I need to perform the logic on all records for this particular entity, and I need the logic to run regularly, i.e. daily/weekly. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. It was actually possible to do entirely within Crm. What I was trying to do was the following.

- I have a custom entity called announcement, and it has a custom field called embargo date.
- I needed to somehow check periodically if the embargo date has been reached, meaning, is the embargo date today? If so, then I needed to change the owner of this entity.
- If the embargo date has not yet been reached, then I need to wait until it is, checking the date again everyday till it is reached.
- I managed this with a workflow. I added my check conditions, if they were true I assigned the entity to another user.
- If my conditions weren't true, I added wait step to wait for 1 day,then another step to Start workflow where I called the current workflow recursively. Meaning, if the conditions aren't true have the workflow call itself again.